# Why does youtube googleapis redirect to a network attack message?

Tags: networking, youtube

For the past few days, YouTube links that worked before such as [this](https://www.youtube.googleapis.com/v/__tPaFaPCHo%26source=uds%26autoplay=1) have been giving me this error message:

```
 Your connection is not private

 Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
 www.youtube.googleapis.com (for example, passwords, messages, or
 credit cards).

 www.youtube.googleapis.com normally uses
 encryption to protect your information. When Chrome tried to connect
 to www.youtube.googleapis.com this time, the website sent back unusual
 and incorrect credentials. Either an attacker is trying to pretend to
 be www.youtube.googleapis.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has
 interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because
 Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

 You cannot visit www.youtube.googleapis.com right now because the
 website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary,
 so this page will probably work later.

 NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Are other people seeing a network attack message with the link above, or is it just an issue with my local router? It occurs not only in Chrome but Firefox and Explorer (on two laptops that I tested) What should I do?

Comment: Are you a developer? Or a regular YouTube user?

Comment: Add the exception to your browser if you trust youtube.